# How to do touch and drag slide animation

Tags: android, animation

[image: how to achive this kind of animation.]

I am trying to code a audio player that streams audio from internet all is going well, but i want an animation look like this.

**EDITED**

This is my Activity:

[image: myActivity]

My Activity Explained :P

[image: Explained]

My Layout XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="70dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/newactivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@color/md_teal_500"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end">

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                android:maxHeight="3dp"
                android:minHeight="3dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar"
                android:thumb="@null"
                />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:text="No Marasiya Selected"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/album"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Album"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#80cbc4"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/duration"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/album"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/album"
                    android:text="00:00"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#80cbc4"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalSec"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/duration"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/duration"
                    android:text=" / 00:00"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#80cbc4"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_button"
            android:tint="@color/md_brown_700"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have using `viewpager` with fragments added to main activity. And the bottom bar is added in main xml layout itself

Comment: I have just tried custom animations but not giving what i needed!

Comment: I just need some library that can do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using AndroidSlidingUpPanel. You can get the demo code from here: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel. Simply add the following dependency to your build.gradle file to use this.

```
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.1'
```

After that edit the following xml for your specific use:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DemoActivity" >

<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
    sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/list">

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            sothree:theme="@style/ActionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Main Content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/dragView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/follow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Below the main  MAIN CONTENT add your viewpager. Below SLIDING LAYOUT add your linear layout

UPDATE: AppCompat v23.2 have introduced BottomSheetBehavior behavior in CoordinatorLayout.

By attaching a BottomSheetBehavior to a child View of a CoordinatorLayout (i.e., adding app:layout_behavior=”android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior”), you’ll automatically get the appropriate touch detection to transition between five state:

- STATE_COLLAPSED: this collapsed state is the default and shows just a
  portion of the layout along the bottom. The height can be controlled
  with the app:behavior_peekHeight attribute (defaults to 0)
- STATE_DRAGGING: the intermediate state while the user is directly
  dragging the bottom sheet up or down
- STATE_SETTLING: that brief time between when the View is released and
  settling into its final position
- STATE_EXPANDED: the fully expanded state of the bottom sheet, where
  either the whole bottom sheet is visible (if its height is less than
  the containing CoordinatorLayout) or the entire CoordinatorLayout is
  filled
- STATE_HIDDEN: disabled by default (and enabled with the
  app:behavior_hideable attribute), enabling this allows users to swipe
  down on the bottom sheet to completely hide the bottom sheet

You can get a sample app for implementing this from here: https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/BottomSheetSample

Comment: Thanks @Jossy Paul. i am going to try this!

Comment: Please can you explain me the layout for using this library because its a bit complicated @Jossy Paul

Comment: OK Done! Its Sliding but how add stuff in panel that is appeared